# ImportError: can't import openpyxl

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, openpyxl

I'm working in Spyder with the Anaconda interpreter. Python version is 3.10.5. Tried installing openpyxl with both the Windows CMD and the Anaconda prompt and they are both telling me openpyxl is installed. But Spyder stills throws the same errors:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.
```

There is no other Python version installed on my PC. What should I do?

Comment: You'll need to configure Spider to use the correct Python executable for which openpyxl is installed. Given that you used Anaconda, you may need to look into configurting Spyder properly for Anaconda.

Comment: @9769953 If you mean setting the python interpreter to anaconda in Spyder then I have already done that. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Did you install openpyxl in the Anaconda base environment? And is the Python interpreter you configured in that base environment as well?

Comment: The environment and configuration of newly installed modules seems to be a [common problem working with Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder).  Did you try anything of the docs?

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely happening is that Spyder is not using the correct Python interpreter. If you're launching Spyder from the Anaconda navigator, it doesn't take the env you launched it from in all cases.

Is the conda env where you installed openpyxl the one listed at the bottom of the Spyder window?

[image: Bottom Spyder Panel]

If not, click it and chose the path to your python.exe file in the Anaconda env (example below).

[image: Settings for Python interpreter]

Answer (score 0):

So, I am not sure this technically qualifies for an answer but my problem was solved.

I solved the issue by uninstalling Anaconda and Spyder. I had installed Spyder first, then Anaconda which probably messed up the environments. The morale of the story: only install Anaconda and let it set up everything for you automatically.

Answer (score -3):

Try below commands to reinstall openpyxl in both Anaconda & system.

```
pip uninstall openpyxl

python -m pip install openpyxl
```

or

```
python3 -m pip3 install openpyxl
```

verify by

```
pip3 show openpyxl
```

Comment: `pip install` is unlikely to be the issue here. The question states the package was installed successfully.